# #Update and Append in Teradata. /* Update existing records in table 1 from table 2. Append new records in table 1 if table 2 have new record */

Tags: sql, teradata

I have table1 as

[image]

I have table2 as

[image]

I need to update table1 with table2 values. same mbr_id records in both table should be replaced by table2 value. new mbr_id in table2 should append to table1.

Expected output:

[image]

My approach

1. separate existing mbr_id and new mbr_id from table2

```
create table set1 as select * from table2 where mbr_id not in (select mbr_id from table1)
create table set2 as select *  from table2 where mbr_id in (select mbr_id from table1)
```

2. Append set1 to table1

```
insert into table1 select * from set1
```

3. update table1 with set2

```
UPDATE t1
FROM table1  t1,
set2 t2
SET 
sales_bucket = t2.sales_bucket,
pro = t2.pro,
Region = t2.Region
where t1.mbr_id = t2.mbr_id
```

The question is: Is there any better way to perform the same in a single go ?

Comment: Yep, there is. Check the `MERGE` syntax.

Comment: I will try that @dnoeth

Answer (score 0):

The MERGE statement combines the UPDATE and INSERT statements into a single statement with two conditional test clauses:
WHEN MATCHED, UPDATE.
WHEN NOT MATCHED, INSERT.
You can also use the MERGE statement to delete rows by specifying: WHEN MATCHED, DELETE.

Comment: Thank you @Mohammed. I am using Merge